# How to use getMetaProperty or access metaData in store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

At some place in my application I build dynamically grids like so:

```
 grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns)
```

And it works nice, although I do not know how exactly store and meta are populated. The code which triggers this operation does not tell me too much:

```
grid.store.addListener('metachange', this.metaChanged, this);
```

So, these parameters - store and meta - come from some internals of `metachange` event, which I do not know. And now what I want in some other place of my application is to do the same `reconfigure` procedure, however, this time I should pass these two variables - store and meta - manually. There is no problem with store - I have it, but I do not know how to find this `meta` object. I guess this is what `getMetaProperty` method exists for. But I tried this:

```
alert(store.getMetaProperty())
```

and it does not work. So, I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `meta` object can be found in the reader associated with your proxy. Looks like it has said method `getMetaProperty()`.
Since you have the store's reference, you can access the reader and get what you need from him:

`store.getProxy().getReader()`

[Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader).

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like an answer! What seems to work is `store.getProxy().getReader().metaData`.